# How to make a group of pictures responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

I have a style for how I want my pictures to appear but I can not get them to be responsive. What do I need to do to make these group of pictures responsive? Currently the result is that the pictures get slimmer. This is the result of the code I have provided below:

[image]

```css
.hall-way {
    /*background-color:red;*/
    height: 400px;
}

.hall-way img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.espaco-office {
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.espaco-office img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;  
}

.espaco-gallery img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.espaco-gallery {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.espaco-stand img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.espaco-stand{
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.espaco-lounge {
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.espaco-lounge img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.espaco-waiting-room {
    height: 600px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}


.espaco-waiting-room img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.espaco-soufa {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.espaco-soufa img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.espaco-modelling {
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.espaco-modelling img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7 hall-way">
                    <img srcset="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery1.png");?> 1x, <?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery1.png");?> 2x" src="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery1.png");?>"> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 espaco-office">
                    <img src="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery5.png");?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5" >
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 espaco-gallery">
                        <img src="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery2.png");?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 espaco-stand">
                        <img src="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery3.png");?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 espaco-lounge">
                    <img src="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery4.png");?>" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 espaco-waiting-room">
                <img src="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery6.png");?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 espaco-soufa">
                <img src="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery7.png");?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 espaco-modelling">
                <img src="<?= base_url("assets/img/main-site/galery8.png");?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use bootstrap, simply add class="img-responsive" to every img (you can do it dynamically as you charge the img tag)

Answer (score 2):

you should use bootstrap's class "img-responsive"

or better way is use

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

that will make ur all images responsive and adjust height of image based on width

hope it helps

Comment: With the class img-responsive it does not work. With max-width: 100%;
height: auto; on the div i get the responsive effect i want but since my height is auto all my img lose the intended height.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of your images to auto

```
 img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: My img disappeared.

Comment: Sorry, ammended. I was thinking of responsive background images.

Comment: Am going to try it with background-images

Comment: For background images it's height: 0; padding-bottom: 100%; background-size: 100% auto; with the padding coming from the width of the parent element. The 100% should then be adjusted to the correct ratio of the image